# Can't install windows10 with Parallels Desktop on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, parallels

I have updated my Mac to Catalina, and I want to install a virtual system windows10, but it always failed, can anybody help?

[image: black screen]
[image: catalina]

Comment: Catalina is a beta, Parallels is not yet ready for it & won't be fully qualified until after release. You need to report the errors to both Apple & Parallels.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank u, i have reported it to apple,  they said they need 1 or 2 days to reply